# How can we auto rotate/scroll collectionView when its controller is loaded?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I followed  [this raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel)
 regarding circular collectionview. I want to rotate it automatically when its controller is loaded. and want to stop it on any random index after rotation. Any one can help me out

[image: End Result should be this, selected cell is bigger than other cells]

Comment: Send fake touch events if this work for you..